# Is reputation change for "User was removed" accurate?

Tags: support, reputation

Before the deletion of a user, I thought I had 4769 reputation. I received a notification of +2 rep for "User was removed", but now I have 4768 reputation.

What is incorrect? The 4769, the +2, the 4768, or the assumption that mathematics works as normal in Stack Exchange?